# Lookup Value with Multiple Search Keys

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do a lookup based on multiple search keys.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

**Sheet Name: Main**

| ID | Course 1 | Course 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111111 |  |  |
| 2222222222 |  |  |

Here are the course codes (or keys).

**Sheet Name: Courses**

| Course 1 | Course 2 |
| --- | --- |
| abc | def |
| abc1 | def1 |
| abc2 |  |

And here is the dataset we are pulling the date from

**Sheet Name: Completion Dataset**

| Course Code | ID | Completion Status | Completion Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1111111111 | Completed | 8/25/2023 |
| abc1 | 2222222222 | Completed | 8/24/2023 |
| abc1 | 3333333333 | Completed | 8/23/2023 |
| def1 | 1111111111 | Not Completed |  |
| def | 2222222222 | Completed | 8/21/2023 |
| abc2 | 3333333333 | Completed | 8/21/2023 |

The result should look like this (**Notice course 2 for 11111111 was not completed so the value is blank**):

| ID | Course 1 | Course 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111111 | 8/25/2023 |  |
| 2222222222 | 8/24/2023 | 8/21/2023 |

I know <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> / <kbd>VLOOKUP( )</kbd> only accept one value as their first parameter (value to lookup). this would require multiple values to be looked up. If multiple parameters show as completed with dates it can bring back the earliest date or first value found since they should be sorted ascending by date.

Comment: You need `FILTER( )` function here. Look at this **[one](https://imgur.com/gallery/oY4Rz7u)**

Comment: I clicked on the link and I see an image. Anyway to post that as an answer? I'll review it.

Comment: do you have access to `HSTACK()` and `TAKE()` as far I know last time you had no access to `TOCOL()` function it was in your last post, can you confirm?

Comment: I don't have any of those on my excel. I think I'm going to switch this dataset over to google sheets. They have ```HSTACK()``` and ```ToCOL()```. No ```TAKE()``` though.

Comment: posted a better alternative in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula: a combination of <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> and <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a, XLOOKUP(
        FILTER(
            $E$2:$F$4,
            B$1 = $E$1:$F$1
        ) & "|" & $A2,
        $H$2:$H$7 & "|" &
            $I$2:$I$7,
        $K$2:$K$7
     ),
     FILTER(a, ISNUMBER(a), "")
 )
```

---

You may need to change the range and cell references as per your suit. Formula needs to be filled down and filled right.

---

[image]

---

Comment: you mention this is added to B2. Does it populate for all of the cells in column B and C?

Comment: No, you need to fill down and fill right ! Look I added one `.Gif`

Comment: @DanCue does that help to resolve ? are you able to understand the formula, it is not very complicated, as far as I think. Can you confirm?

Comment: I'm trying to change this to suit my needs. I'm getting N/As. I'm sure it is my fault, so I'm trying to understand what the formula is doing so I can correct it. As soon as I figure it out I will let you know.

Comment: @DanCue do you have a sample excel file, can you post a link here. ?

Comment: good Idea. Let me put that together.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HH0FPfSEMrM_6bp_ZhbyVCHiuKeF53lCtI8L2x_NAH0/edit#gid=2100307022

Comment: Excellent. I just needed to change A2 to $A2 in the formula. Thank you!

Comment: @DanCue glad to know it worked out for you =)

Comment: oh. I just realized that if there are two courses completed by the same person that are under the same course column it will try to bring back an array. How do I only bring back the first result?

Comment: Ok, let me see the sheet again. Btw are you using `Excel` or `Google Sheets`? If `Excel` then adding an `Implicit Intersection Operator @` will always show you the first one.

Comment: I'll add a scenario to it so you see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'll stick with Google sheets on this one.

Comment: Alright formula already has been updated

Comment: This works well. Thank you. I may have to figure out how to do this through script though and then copy paste. It's taking a while to load on all the cells and this dataset will change daily. I really appreciate your help. This gets me what I need for now!